# Test json result with hamcrest, order agnostic

Tags: java, rest-assured, hamcrest

I have an API that returns the following kind of body result, and I want to test it with Hamcrest on java17.

```
[
    {
        "name": "name1",
        "version": "x.x.x"
    },
    {
        "name": "name2",
        "version": "y.y.y"
    }
]
```

I woud like to test that I always get version = "x.x.x" for name1, and version = "y.y.y" for name2.

The following code works, but I would like a more order-agnostic test, as it takes into account the order of my elements:

```
given()...when()...then()
   .body("name[0]", is("foo"))
   .body("version[0]", is("0.0.0"))
   .body("name[1]", is("bar"))
   .body("version[1]", is("1.1.1"));
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
.body("find {it.name == 'name1'}.version", is("x.x.x"))
.body("find {it.name == 'name2'}.version", is("y.y.y"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works !
Here is some documentation for those who are interested : https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#example-3---complex-parsing-and-validation